# Wordpress custom field only displaying 10 posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I've used wordpress **Advanced Custom Fields** plugin to make my portfolio page. I've setup fields for the image, title, category and a yes/no for weather the project is featured.

My code for the project page is as follows:

```
<?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'project'
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>

<?php Starkers_Utilities::get_template_parts( array( 'parts/shared/html-header', 'parts/shared/header' ) ); ?>

<h1 class="lead"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

<div id="triggers">
    <strong>Filter:</strong>
    <span id="filterDouble">Filter All</span>   
    <span id="filter1">Filter 1</span>
    <span id="filter2">Filter 2</span>
</div>

<ul id="gallery" class="group">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

        <li class="gallery_image" data-id="id-" data-type="<?php the_field('project_category')?>">

                <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" class="zoom" href="<?php echo the_field('image') ?>">

                    <img class="mag" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/imgs/mag.png"/><div class="thumb_bg"></div>
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('portfolio'); ?>
                </a>                                    


        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

Everything works fine, i can add projects. However **My problem starts** when i hit 10 projects. After 10, it doesn't display anymore. I am using jpages (jquery plugin) and filtrify to add filters to filer out the categories. They work fine, i can filter by category and i see the correct images. Even with the plugin scripts removed, i still only see a max of 10 posts. Adding more than 10 simply pushes the earlier images off and it displays the 10 latest.

So how can i stop it from being just 10.. My jpage script sets the pagination to 12 per page, but this doesn't even get a chance to kick in. I am thinking it's a post problem as I'm certain it's not the scripts.

**I think I've traced an issue** - I tested this: `'posts_per_page' => '20'` - Which DOES display my missing posts, however i don't want to set a number as i might need lots. How can i define an unlimited number. Providing this is the issue..

If any other code is needed, please let me know, but i think this is the main part of what's controlling my posts appearing on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track.Set the value to `-1` to get your desired results.

Link to the documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters

> posts_per_page (int) - number of post to show per page (available with Version 2.1, replaced showposts parameter). **Use 'posts_per_page'=>-1 to show all posts**. Set the 'paged' parameter if pagination is off after using this parameter.

Comment: Ah i can't believe i didn't find that :) Thank you!

Comment: do you need the -1 in single quotes?